# Android Activity Not Found Exception: No Activity Found to handle Intent

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

This seems like it should be easy to fix, there are several posts with example code for different examples, more complex. Yet none have worked for this simple program.

The BMI Calculator has two activities, MainActivity and BMIResultsScreen. The user enters their weight and height in the MainActivity and views results in the BMIResultsScreen. They can then opt to click a button to exit or click a button to return to the MainActivity. The exit button works but the button to return to MainActivity does not.

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.username.bmicalculator">

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".BMIResultsScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.username.BMIResultsScreen" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

The MainActivity:

```
  package com.example.username.bmicalculator

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setOnClickListenerForButton()
}

fun calculateBMI(): Double {
    var weight: Double = (numWeight.getText().toString().toDouble())
    var height: Double = (numHeight.getText().toString().toDouble())
    var calculatedBMI = (((weight / height) / height))
    return calculatedBMI
}

fun setOnClickListenerForButton() {
    btnCalculateBMI.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent("com.example.username.BMIResultsScreen")
        intent.putExtra("BMIResult", calculateBMI())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
}
```

The second activity, BMIResultScreen:

```
 package com.example.username.bmicalculator

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Intent
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_bmiresults_screen.*
import java.text.DecimalFormat


class BMIResultsScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmiresults_screen)

        showBMIResult()
        findBMICategory()
        setExitListener()
        setCheckAgainListener()
    }

    fun showBMIResult(){
        var decFormat = DecimalFormat("#.#")
        var formattedBMI = decFormat.format(getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("BMIResult"))
        lblBMIResult.setText(formattedBMI.toString())
    }

    fun findBMICategory() {
        var categoryOfBMI = "Unknown"
        var resultBMI = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("BMIResult")
        if (resultBMI < 15) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Very Severely Underweight"
        } else if (resultBMI in 15..16) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Severely Underweight"
        } else if (resultBMI > 16 && resultBMI <= 18.5) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Underweight"
        } else if (resultBMI > 18.5 && resultBMI <= 25) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Normal (Healthy Weight)"
        } else if (resultBMI in 25..30) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Overweight"
        } else if (resultBMI in 30..35) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Moderately Obese"
        } else if (resultBMI in 35..40) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Severely Obese"
        } else if (resultBMI >= 40) {
            categoryOfBMI = "Very Severely Obese"
        }
        lblBMIResultCategory.setText(categoryOfBMI)
    }

        fun setExitListener() {
            btnExit.setOnClickListener {
                this.finishAffinity()
            }
        }

            fun setCheckAgainListener() {
                btnCheckAgain.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent("com.example.username.bmicalculator.MainActivity")
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `onBackPressed()` inside the listener for the button that returns to the Main activity.

```
          btnCheckAgain.setOnClickListener {
                this.onBackPressed()
            }
```